# Rooting the Galaxy S3 Without a Computer

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, rooting, verizon

Is it possible to root the Galaxy S3 without a computer? If so, what would the process be? My Galaxy S3 is with Verizon and is currently running Android 4.3.

Comment: Related **Methods/Apps** here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed.

**DISCLAIMER**: Rooting may brick your device and invalidate your carrier and manufacturer warranty. **I didn't write the guide below** (***full credit is due to the poster on XDA*** Developers, and I have left the words 'my' in place but it is HIS work), and it is your responsibility to check you are happy to proceed. HERE BE DRAGONS.

This guide was written in July of 2013 and I can't say for sure if it will work on Android 4.3 and your particular bootloader at all. I have not tested this method.

Rooting form a PC is easier and has less scope for human errors and is liklier to work in general.

[This XDA thread is relating to the sprint version](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2352669) but should apply to the S3 general.

**Prerequisites**

The following files are attached to this post for convenience. Download and install the apps, download and extract the zip file somewhere convenient.
Superuser by Koush(MUST be this one. You can change it later if you so desire.) 
Terminal Emulator by Jack Palevich ( MUST be this one) 
Zip file, extracted somewhere convenient

**THE GOODS**

These generic names will be used:
/path/to/motochopperDir - This is the full path to the extracted motochopper-mobile DIRECTORY or FOLDER. Example: /sdcard/motochopper-mobile (will vary depending on where you extracted the files).

NOTE: After running the script, Motochopper may or may not print "Failed", but the exploit DOES indeed work regardless of this. Make sure you reboot for changes to take effect.

Download the attached zip file AND both apps. 
Install Terminal Emulator and Superuser (use a file manager, navigate to the downloaded .apk files and click on each file to install them). 
Open up Terminal Emulator and type the following commands. Press the ENTER key after each command.

Code:

```
cd /path/to/motochopperDir
cat setup.sh > /data/data/jackpal.androidterm/setup.sh
cd /data/data/jackpal.androidterm
chmod 755 setup.sh

./setup.sh /path/to/motochopperDir
```

From there, my setup.sh script will handle the rest of the process. If you are still unsure, see my sample run below.

Sample run (files were extracted to /sdcard/moto)

```
cd /sdcard/moto
cat setup.sh > /data/data/jackpal.androidterm/setup.sh
cd /data/data/jackpal.androidterm
chmod 755 setup.sh
./setup.sh /sdcard/moto
```

**The Links**:

[Android Term.apk](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2097851&d=1373168462)

[Super User](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2097852&d=1373168462)

[MotoChopper](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2097853&d=1373168462)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no computer-less method of rooting the Samsung Galaxy S3 unfortunately.

Comment: There actually is one! Whether it works on particular bootloaders or firmwares has to be checked on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can root without a computer as long as you already have a recovery mode that lets you install from a zip.

I have just rooted an S3 i9300, the stock international unlocked model, this way. Its specifications are

- Model GT-I9300
- Android 4.3
- Kernel 3.0.31-2168382 Thu Nov 28 21:02.26 KST 2013

I had previously installed [ClockWorkMod Recovery](https://www.clockworkmod.com) (the *touch* version [6.0.4.6](http://download2.clockworkmod.com/recoveries/recovery-clockwork-touch-6.0.4.6-i9300.img)) on it and I used a [Linux computer](https://www.archlinux.org) and the [Heimdall](http://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall) application to do that. So this isn't a strictly computer-free solution due to the CWM prerequisite but it does demonstrate (and perhaps demystify) how to root.

First, I used the phone's Chrome browser to download *Super SU* from http://download.chainfire.eu/supersu. The version that I got was `UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.46.zip`.

I then rebooted the phone into CWM (press and hold `UP` `HOME` and `POWER` for 20+ seconds).

I selected `install ZIP`, then `choose zip from /sdcard`, then browsed through `0/` and `Download/` to locate the `UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.46.zip` file. I then selected `YES` perform the install.

When the install completed, I used `+++++Go Back+++++` twice to return to the main menu where I selected `Reboot system now`.

CWM showed a warning that `Root access possibly lost`. I declined the offer to fix that by selecting `No`.

The phone rebooted.

I then confirmed the presence of the [Super SU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu&hl=en) app and used the [Root checker Basic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&hl=en) app to confirm that I now had root access. I also confirmed that I could now use `su -` from a shell (I use the [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&hl=en) terminal app).

Answer (score 0):

I used [towelroot](https://towelroot.com/) on my SCH-I535 and it worked perfectly.